# Laravel 8 return flock error on api request

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm very stuck with an error that i can't understand, Laravel 8 response always `"flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given"` In all api routes. I made a simple route to debug this issue but i'm not have a little idea what the problem is, so if someone could get me some help about this i'll be would be great.
This is my code:

**API Routes**

```
Route::post('/createUser',[UserController::class, 'store'])->name('createUser');
Route::get('/getUser',[UserController::class, 'index'])->name('getUser');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('V1')->group(function () {
        
        // Rutas para los VDP
        Route::get('/conf',[ReaderController::class, 'readerInitialConf'])->name('readerInitialConf');
        Route::post('/createReader',[ReaderController::class, 'store'])->name('createReader');


    });
});
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public function index()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
```

**And this is Postman:**

[image]

**Note**: This application is dockerized, I don't know if docker might  cause this problem, but i think not, because i always use it and never get this problem.

If someone could help, i'll be very thankfull.

Thanks in advance!
Raul

Comment: It looks to me like a file permission issue

Comment: Make sure you have the folder permissions setup properly on the docker container: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#directory-permissions

Comment: I thought in folder permissions and i ran chmod -R 777 in both folders... but i ran it again and i notice that some files in storage/cache still got 755, so the api is responding ok now... Thanks a lot to both of you!!!

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 11):

Check permissions of `storage/framework/cache/data` just to define 777 to the `storage/framework/cache` won't be enough, you should also give the `webserver` user permissions to write into that folder, typically the user is: `www-data` or `_www`.

The right thing is to have `775` permissions to this folder then change only the grupo to allow both your user and the webserver user to write into those folders.

```sh
chmod 775 storage/framework/cache
chmod 775 storage/framework/cache/data

sudo chgrp www-data storage/framework/cache
sudo chgrp www-data storage/framework/cache/data
```